# PHP - WSDL - complex type usage

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, webservice-client

I want to write a Soap-Service in PHP.
My WSDL-looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://myserver.net"  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="myService" targetNamespace="http://myserver.net">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="getArticleStockInput">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="articleid" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="getArticleStockOutput">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="stock" type="xsd:float"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </wsdl:types> 
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleStockRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleStockInput" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleStockResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleStockOutput" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="myServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleStock">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getArticleStockRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getArticleStockResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>   
  </wsdl:portType>  
  <wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoapHttpBinding" type="tns:myServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleStock">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://myserver.net/getArticleStock"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ShopService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:myServiceSoapHttpBinding" name="ShopServiceSOAP11prt_HTTP">
      <soap:address location="http://myserver.net/ws.php5"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My Server:

```
$SOAPServer = new SoapServer("wsdl.wsdl");
$SOAPServer->addFunction('getArticleStock');
$SOAPServer->handle();

function getArticleStock($parm)
{
    $fd = fopen("./log.dat", "a+");
    fwrite($fd,print_r($parm,1)."\n");
    fclose($fd);
}
```

Now i have two questions.
Client 1

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$url="http://myserver.net/wsdl.wsdl"; 
$client3 = new SoapClient($url);

$parray = array("articleid" => "150");          
$result = $client3->__soapCall("getArticleStock", array("getArticleStockInput"=>$parray));
```

=> Server Output in Log

```
stdClass Object
(
    [item] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => articleid
            [value] => 150
        )
)
```

Why does the output in Log / PHP not show the Soap Message Name getArticleStockRequest?

If I write the client like this:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$url="http://myserver.net/wsdl.wsdl"; 
$client3 = new SoapClient($url);

$parray = array("articleid" => "150");          
$result = $client3->__soapCall("getArticleStock", $parray);
```

the log only contains:

```
150
```

Is it possible to get the parm name articleid in this case?

Bye jogi

Comment: Is that the whole of the WSDL file? It doesn't look right to me ... shouldn't it have a top level element of `<definitions>` containing the messages and everything else? Admittedly I've never hand-written one before...

Comment: it was only a part of the wsdl - i changed it an put the whole wsdl in the question.

Comment: I think... and I may be wrong here, essentially what happens when you call `$client3->__soapCall("getArticleStock", $parray);` is that the values from the array `$parray` are passed in as the parameters of the function `getArticleStock()` (much like with `call_user_func_array('function', $arrayOfParameterValues)`) so I think it's just the values that have any meaning, the "keys" would essentially be the parameter variable names.

Comment: ok, thanks so far. But what is the right way to handle the data in the server? The webservice should be used by different users.